# Define range for sum/sumif with a formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup, sumifs

I've been going up and down the internet to solve this. I think I am not searching with the correct parameters but I still hope you can help me.

Sample table:

[image: Sample table]

I have some consolidation forms I need to fill with sums. So, in C19 (which is actually on a new tab) I would like to sum all the values C5-C12 which are mapped to the AB100 account for the consolidation, in production for example. The AB100 account is not unique to production, so I first need to define the column in which the specific row(s) have to be used to sum the values. Automating that in a formula is my key issue here.

I could easily solve this by just selecting column E as range for SUMIF but I want the formula in C19 to be able to recognize which column is to be looked at automatically, e.g. by using a "Lookup Key". I have many of those consolidation forms and I don't want to manually change the formulas on each tab.

It seems to me that all tips I found for nested SUM(IF( or SUM(INDEX( - even as array formulas - have the result value on the intersection of matched row and column. What I have on that intersection is a range of identical account numbers which need to be matched back to their respective $ values in C5-C12.

Any idea how I can do this with a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(D5:F12,0,MATCH(C16,D4:F4,0)),B19,C5:C12)
```

Comment: Just as simple as that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using an index formula to select the column required in the SUMIFS

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Please put the formula as text so the OP can copy paste and not need to retype.